# Take a screenshot of the whole screen in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to take a screenshot of the whole view that the user is seeing. I want to achieve the same result as pressing the lock and home button programmatically.

I know there are a lot of questions like mine, but they all require me to input a specific view. What about all the views?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example on how to take a screenshot at [TLB Tech Entries](http://techblog.tiffanyb.net/2011/04/05/programmatically-taking-a-screenshot-of-your-app-in-ios/). The code shows you how to define the dimensions of the screen, create the snapshot, put the entire view into the snapshot and save the subsequent image to a photo album.

You can also refer back to the Apple's [UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) framework for more details on the commands used.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this did the trick but no. It returns only a white image.